# Using TabView without TabActivity android

Tags: android

Is it possible to use TabView without using TabActivity.

All samples I could find are based on TabActivity only.

Can someone please point to a sample where TabView is used as a child of activity to host another set of activities in its tabs

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a ViewPager and then you can add tabs to show the current fragment of the view pager:

[ViewPager with tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)